# SharePoint 2010 - User Photos copy from Stage in Prod. Enviroment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

It is possible to copy the User Photos from the Stage in the Prod. Enviroment?
Photo root directory: http://mysharepoint.de/User Photos/Profilbidler (Because it is German)

It is only necessary to copy the three photos per user from Stage to Prod. Env. in the root directory?

Photos per user in the root directory:

- Domain_UserName_LThumb.jpg
- Domain_UserName_MThumb.jpg
- Domain_UserName_SThumb.jpg

Comment: This is a great question, because I hadn't even thought about it until you asked, but now that I've thought it through I know it is very easy to do. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's a document library so you can work with it like other libraries. Probably the easiest is to enter the address in the browser, http://mysharepoint.de/User Photos/Profilbidler , and then select Open in Windows Explorer from the Actions menu. You can do the same in production and copy them over.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) could help

> The SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard is a tool for *SharePoint 2007/2010* which
>   provides the means to deploy the following content:
>
> - site collections
> - webs
> - lists
> - folders
> - list items (including files)